# checkbox:checked applying styles to image and text but not the label

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm using checkbox:checked function to toggle between the image and the text for a profile card, but whatever I've tried there's no effect on the label button.

```
<input class="adg-team-wrapper-check" type="checkbox" name="" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $team_slug ) . '-check'; ?>">
<div class="adg-team-wrapper-content">
  <?php
  if ( $team_pic && is_array( $team_pic ) ) :
    echo sprintf(
      '<img id="%1$s" class="adg-team-wrapper-image w-100 h-100" src="%2$s" alt="%3$s" title="%4$s">',
      esc_html( $team_slug . '-pic' ),
      esc_attr( $team_pic['url'] ),
      esc_attr( $team_pic['alt'] ),
      esc_attr( $team_pic['title'] )
    );
  endif;
  echo '<div class="adg-team-wrapper-text">' . wp_kses_post( $team_description ) . '</div>'             
  ?>
</div>
<?php 
echo sprintf( '<h4 id="%1$s" class="adg-team-wrapper-title adg-txt-gold">%2$s</h4>', 
  $team_slug . '-name',
  $team_name 
); 
?>
  
<p class="adg-team-wrapper-extract"><?php echo esc_html( $team_role ); ?></p>
<label class="adg-team-wrapper-label" for="<?php echo esc_attr( $team_slug ) . '-check'; ?>">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
</label>
```

```
&:checked {
    + .adg-team-wrapper-content {
      > .adg-team-wrapper-image {
      width: 0% !important;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    .adg-team-wrapper-text {
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
    }
          
    .adg-team-wrapper-label {
      transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
  }
}
```

I can't workout why the rotate(135deg) isn't applying when the checkbox is checked

Comment: Isn't it outside `adg-team-wrapper-content`?

Comment: Solved! With a really really ugly bodge


`+ .adg-team-wrapper-content + .adg-team-wrapper-title + .adg-team-wrapper-extract + .adg-team-wrapper-label {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comment, I think that you can update your selector a bit:

```
.adg-team-wrapper-check {
  &:checked {
    + .adg-team-wrapper-content {
      > .adg-team-wrapper-image {
        width: 0% !important;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
      }

      .adg-team-wrapper-text {
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    ~ .adg-team-wrapper-label {
      display: inline-block;
      transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
  }  
}
```

It will compile to:

```css
.adg-team-wrapper-check:checked + .adg-team-wrapper-content > .adg-team-wrapper-image {
  width: 0% !important;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.adg-team-wrapper-check:checked + .adg-team-wrapper-content .adg-team-wrapper-text {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.adg-team-wrapper-check:checked ~ .adg-team-wrapper-label {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<input class="adg-team-wrapper-check" type="checkbox" name="" id="team_slug">
<div class="adg-team-wrapper-content">
  content
</div>
<p class="adg-team-wrapper-extract">team_role</p>
<label class="adg-team-wrapper-label" for="team_slug">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
  label
</label>
```